# How to select elements with same values using xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

How to click on the element with the value "Policy Search", which has dynamic attributes for each users, so please help me to set the xpath for below code.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse in">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/AgentWeb/secured/home.xhtml">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Business <b class="caret"></b></a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="/AgentWeb/secured/agentHierarchy.xhtml">Agent Hierarchy</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/AgentWeb/secured/bob/newBusinessSearch.xhtml">Pending New Business</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="/AgentWeb/secured/bob/inforceBusinessSearch.xhtml">Book of Business</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="/AgentWeb/secured/commissions/commissionsDefault.xhtml">Commissions</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/AgentWeb/secured/licenseRenewals.xhtml">License Renewals</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/AgentWeb/secured/bob/trialAppPolicySearch.xhtml">Trial Applications</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Policy Search <b class="caret"></b></a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="dropdown-submenu"> <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Book of Business Search</a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="/AgentWeb/secured/clientSearch.xhtml">Client Search</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="/AgentWeb/secured/policybobSearch.xhtml">Policy Search</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="/AgentWeb/secured/advanceSearch.xhtml">Advanced Search</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: If it's a dropdown item, you could always preform human interaction( Working with keyboard -wise )  as like making your webdriver go ' 1 arrowkey down ' and click it. And it's easier then xpathing :p

Answer (score 0):

```
By.xpath("//a[contains(@class="dropdown-toggle" and text()="Policy Search")]));
```

and if you have multiple items with same value, you can specify it like,

```
By.xpath("//a[contains(text()="Policy Search")][1]));
By.xpath("//a[contains(text()="Policy Search")][2]));
```

Comment: Thanks, If your problem got resolved, you can pretty much accept it, so to avoid others time as well, into looking at your question